# SQL Select row with value between two column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have this table

```
 id  | item_id | count | price 
-----+---------+-------+-------
 127 |       8 |   100 |  2.16
 128 |       8 |   200 |  1.23
 129 |       8 |   300 |  0.91
 130 |       8 |   400 |  0.76
 131 |       8 |   500 |  0.66
 132 |       8 |   600 |  0.54
 133 |       8 |   700 |  0.49
 134 |       8 |   800 |  0.47
 135 |       8 |   900 |  0.45
 136 |       8 |  1000 |  0.41
 137 |       8 |  1500 |  0.36
```

which means that if the client orders between 200 and 300 items the price would be 1.23. I want to find the price for X number of items. I could just modify the tables and make count_min and count_max fields and select on count_min >= X and count_max < X, but I feel there's a more elegant way.

Comment: Storing min and max in a single row would indeed be a more efficient solution. With Postgres you can create a constraint that avoid overlapping rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the list of all prices that are **lesser than** the current quantity, then order by `count` field (in a descending order), and get only 1 result.

You may want to use **lesser or equal than** if, in example, 200 should be included in the range 200 - 300 rather than in the 100 - 200 one.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v10.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE priceListing (
  "id" INTEGER,
  "item_id" INTEGER,
  "count" INTEGER,
  "price" FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO priceListing
  ("id", "item_id", "count", "price")
VALUES
  (127, 8, 100, 2.16),
  (128, 8, 200, 1.23),
  (129, 8, 300, 0.91),
  (130, 8, 400, 0.76),
  (131, 8, 500, 0.66),
  (132, 8, 600, 0.54),
  (133, 8, 700, 0.49),
  (134, 8, 800, 0.47),
  (135, 8, 900, 0.45),
  (136, 8, 1000, 0.41),
  (137, 8, 1500, 0.3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT "price"
FROM priceListing
WHERE "count" < 250 -- Arbitrary value for the range 200 - 300
ORDER BY "count" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Output**

```
| price |
| ----- |
| 1.23  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jEnMScBf2BDJU3HpS7BkTs/1)